# Why when I update my API from amplify CLI removes API gateway cognito Authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm developing a React JS App with AWS amplify, using cognito user pool to auth my users. Then I add a cognito authorizer to the endpoints I wan't to protect.
When I send requests to protected endpoints I send the idToken saved in LocalStorage and in the Auth Session, and everything works fine.
But when I update my API from Amplify CLI the Cognito Authorizer is deleted from API gateway console and all my auth stops working.
Anyone knows why this happen? I'm new on AWS and AWS Amplify. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue,did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Not yet buddy, and I can't find any answers