# Amplify CLI Erasing API Gateway Cognito Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have precisely the same question as the one posited in this post: [Why when I update my API from amplify CLI removes API gateway cognito Authorizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448470/why-when-i-update-my-api-from-amplify-cli-removes-api-gateway-cognito-authorizer). Asking in my own post to see if I get better luck. Thanks!